# How can I mock location.pathname in reactjs

Tags: mock, reactjs, jestjs

I tried all the possibilities to mock `location.pathname`
This is my code

```
if(typeof location !== undefined) {
    this.setParentPath(location.pathname);
}
```

This is one of the possibility I used to cover the `location` as undefined

```
it('should gets the parentPath without location', async () => {
        const locationSpy = jest.spyOn(location);
        locationSpy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);
        await asyncMount(
            <Provider UsersStore={UsersStore} AppStore={AppStore}>
                <Users />
            </Provider>,
        );

        expect(UsersStore.tppPath).toEqual('');
    });
```

It's giving me this error

```
Error: Cannot spy the undefined property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (/Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:789:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/src/components/users/Users.spec.jsx:190:38)
at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:100:37)
at /Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:47:12
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at mapper (/Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:30:19)
at /Users/arpit/Documents/prakhar/new/developer-portal/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:77:41
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Just focusing on location or window elements for this question though..
Please suggest any solution specific to this only not for any
`MemoryRouter` Or any other react-router component

Comment: Ya that i know that it's not making any sense to use in that way... just using location.pathname.. React gives you that functionality to use these directly

Comment: Cannot use MemoryRouter though as per my usecase.

Comment: I have to use window or using location for now..

Comment: The question was asked specifically for location.pathname...

Comment: The question is crystal and clear @jonrshape voting it down doesn't make any sense